# index.d.ts file being resolved to the wrong node_modules folder

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, node-modules, typescript-typings, semantic-ui-react

I've recently started getting IDE errors with a particular import in VSCode. It started occurring I believe since the latest VSCode update, as my modules are locked with yarn and the source shouldn't have changed. To be clear, this code *does* compile, but the IDE is complaining.

My import, `semantic-ui-react`, is being resolved to the dist index.d.ts file in the commonjs output sub directory, but I need it to point to the index.d.ts file in the root of the node module, which is where the components I need to use are declared.

Is there a way to override this?

I've posted the image below elaborate, green being the declaration file required to be imported.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [a SUIR issue](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/issues/2856) with latest TypeScript, it was fixed in [`semantic-ui-react@0.81.0`](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v0810-2018-06-03).

Just update an restart VSCode.